# How can I constantly query a global variable while running a long method in a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop

Right now I have a program that creates 3 threads and runs. It moves a physical piece of hardware. It runs a motor that will continue to move forward unless you tell it to stop, or it hits a physical emergency stop. Sometimes I don't need it to keep going because I have the data I need, and it wastes time and resources if the motor keeps going forward. I want to be able to kill all 3 threads (1 thread moves the motor, 1 thread uses LIDAR to check the distance of the motor mount, and 1 thread checks to see if we have the data we need). Basically once I have the data I need, I want to be able to break out of this.

I tried using something like

```
self.stop = False

while True:
  thread.start()
  if self.stop == True:
    break
```

but it will not actually hit the if statement until the thread is actually done running. I want a way to instantly be able to kill this thread the second a variable changes.

```
def _move_helper(self):
    while True:
      if self.should_abort_immediately:
        LOG.DEBUG("ABORTING")
        return
      self.position_hit = self.move.move_to_position(lab.PHONE_MOTOR, lab.PHONE_SCAN_POSITION, 10)
```

I have also tried various `.joins` with threadding, but that doesn't seem to help me.

I have tried this example as well that I found

```
# Python program killing 
# threads using stop 
# flag 

import threading 
import time 

def run(stop): 
    while True: 
        print('thread running') 
        if stop(): 
                break

def main(): 
        stop_threads = False
        t1 = threading.Thread(target = run, args =(lambda : stop_threads, )) 
        t1.start() 
        time.sleep(1) 
        stop_threads = True
        t1.join() 
        print('thread killed') 
main()
```

I want to be able to set some sort of class or global variable that allows me to kill the thread.

Comment: You can check this article, is directly related to what you are looking https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/starting-and-synchronizing-threads/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second example, put `stop_threads` outside `main` (in the module scope). Then simply change `while True` to `while not stop_threads` in `run()`...

Comment: Combined your solution with Artiom's and this actually worked. Thank you!